# How do I stretch nav bar up while leaving logo where it is?

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting the blue on the navigation bar to go to the top so it covers the grey but not so it covers the border, I also want the logo to remain where it is.[image]

Code is here. http://pastebin.com/YDM1PFMe

Comment: Change margin-top to padding-top on your .sideimage class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the margin-top to a padding-top otherwise the margin is just pushing the content down 50px.

```
.sideimage {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0w742c4f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin here:

```
.sideimage {
    text-align: center;
    //margin-top: 50px;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/35/

and I think your desired effect would be to use `padding-top` instead:

```
.sideimage {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/36/